# Regex.IsMatch not working on target directories

Tags: c#, regex

Can some body help me, I'm new to c#, I know this question has been asked several times before. The code below is supposed to be looking for specific directories but it doesn't seem to match the regex. I have tested the expression on regex101.com and it worked fine.

matching string should return True: `\TestData\FXLH_TestData`

matching string should return False: `\TestData\FXLH_TestData_manifest`

```
string dirReg = "([A-Z]+_TestData)[^_manifest]";

foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(target))
{

  if (Regex.IsMatch(subDir, dirReg)

       Console.WriteLine("success");

  else

       Console.WriteLine("fail");                       
}
```

Comment: `(?!_manifest)` instead of `[^_manifest]`

Comment: Also, you're missing a `)` at the end of your `if` statement

Comment: Wow spot on! (?!_manifest) worked. Thanks a lot ctwheels

Comment: why not just use EndsWith("_TestData") - why do you need regex at all?

Answer (score -1):

if you are looking for the files that end in `_TestData`, you can use this code

```
string dirReg = "_TestData$";

foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(target))
{
  if (Regex.IsMatch(subDir, dirReg))
       Console.WriteLine("success");
  else
       Console.WriteLine("fail");                       
}
```

Comment: Why even use regex then? Just use [EndsWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Exactly my thought, I don't think there is a requirement for regex here.